# Debugging multiple solutions in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, solution

I have 3 solutions like below:

```
Solution A
    ProjectA1 (Console Application)
        References: ProjectB1.dll

Solution B
    ProjectB1 (Web Service)
        References: ProjectC1.dll

Solution C
    ProjectC1 (BL method)
```

The goal is to debug method in ProjectC1 starting from ProjectA1.

What I did:

1) I built all solutions

2) I copied ProjectB1.dll, ProjectB1.pdb, ProjectC1.dll and Project C1.pdb into Solution A\ProjectA1\bin\Debug directory

3) I started debugging ProjectA1

4) During calling web service method by pressing F11 I attached process and continue debugging in ProjectB1

5) During calling BL method from ProjectC1 (in my ProjectB1) by again pressing F11 button I'm not able to step into ProjectC1 (I can see only returned value from BL method) - this time Visual Studio didn't prompt for attaching process to step into ProjectC1 for debugging

Is it possible in this scenario to debug method in ProjectC1 and how can I achive that?

If is it possible I don't want to create Solution D to combine all projects from Solutions from A to C (too much work for me - hundreds of projects in those 3 solutions).

Best regards,

Rafal

Comment: Use one solution with multiple projects that references each other instead.

Comment: @Rafal Cypcer, Since you have resolved this issue, please mark it as the answer, so it would help other community members who meet the same issue. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Zack Zhai I can do that tomorrow. I can mark my answer as resolved after two days from posting the answer (this is some limitation for my account I guess). Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. It turned out that my second step was wrong. It should be:

2a. **Copy ProjectB1.dll** and **ProjectB1.pdb** into **Solution A**\ProjectA1\bin\Debug directory

2b. Copy **ProjectC1.dll** and **Project C1.pdb** into **Solution B**\ProjectB1\bin\Debug directory

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nice sharing:), to debug the (dll) reference, you need the debugging symbols (the "pdb" file) to be in the same folder as the dll.