# Attached Debugger to all open visual studio instances

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

How can I programmatically open multiple solutions in Visual Studio and start debugging them simultaneously?

Comment: I don't know about multiple Solutions, but you can definitely debug multiple projects from one Solution simultaneously, so you could create a custom Solution just for that purpose.

Comment: I have multiple microservices, what I want to achieve is to create a custom script using c# that will open all the services and start the debugger. @500-InternalServerError

Comment: What have you tried to achieve what you described in your question? What did not work? Where do you struggle? Please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: Has your problem been solved

Comment: I attempted to use the EnvDTE library to solve my issue, however, I did not obtain optimal results. The library allows me to open all the solutions and initiate debugging, but it is slow and consumes a lot of memory. Can anyone suggest a more efficient solution? @wenbingeng-MSFT

Comment: @AbdulMoiz Hello, can you tell me why you don't use the method of calling the dll?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this function by calling dll. For example, I have a Project a in Solution a and a Project b in Solution b. At this time, I need to copy the Project b.dll and Project b.pdb to the Solution a\Project a\bin\Debug directory, and then call it. Please refer to the details. [Debugging multiple solutions in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016746/debugging-multiple-solutions-in-visual-studio)